# Proof Line Integral is zero avoiding Stokes

Tags: curves, vector-fields, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Give is: $C$ which is a closed curve which forms the surface $\Sigma$., $\vec{v} $ which is a constant vector.

I should prove the following expression without using Stokes' Theorem:

$$\oint_C  \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{l} = 0$$

How do I go about doing it for an arbitrarily closed (even overlapping) curve ?

Comment: *Constant vector* doesn't mean anything if you don't specify where your curve lives. How is a vector from the tangent space at $p$ equal to a vector from the tangent space at another point $p'$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be parameterized by $\alpha(t)$, where $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Then using the definition of the line integral,

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\mathbf{v} \cdot \alpha'(t) dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} (\mathbf{v} \cdot \alpha(t))' dt = (\mathbf{v} \cdot \alpha(t)) \Big|_{t_0}^{t_1} = 0$$

since $\alpha(t_0) = \alpha(t_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{v}=\langle c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_n\rangle$ be a constant vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $\vec{v}=\nabla f$ for some differentiable function $f$, that is, we can take $f$ to be 
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)=c_1x_1 + c_2 x_2+\ldots + c_n x_n + C, \mbox{ where }C\in \mathbb{R}, 
$$
and $\nabla = \langle \partial_1,\partial_2,\ldots, \partial_n \rangle$, $\partial_i := \partial_{x_i}$, $\vec{v}$ is conservative (and so $\nabla f$ is a gradient field).

Thus a line integral along any smooth curve depends only on the endpoints of the path, i.e., given a parametrization $\vec{l}:[t_1,t_2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ of a smooth closed curve $C$, say 
$$
\vec{l}(t_1) = \vec{l}(t_2)=(p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_n),
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\oint_C \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{l} 
&= \oint_C \nabla f \cdot d\vec{l} \\ 
&= f(\vec{l}(t_2)) - f(\vec{l}(t_1)) \\ 
&= f(p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_n) - f(p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_n) \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Note that if $C$ is not smooth, you can generalize this argument for piecewise smooth curves.